# Expected number of balls surrounded by at least one ball of different color

Tags: probability, combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

Suppose we have 50 black balls and 50 white balls arranged randomly in a circle. Find the expected number of black balls such that at least one of its neighbors is white.

**Proposed solution:**
Let $X_i$ be the random variable taking value $1$ if the i-th black ball has a white neighbor and $0$ otherwise. Then by linearity of expectation, our desired quantity is $50 E[X_i]$. Now
\begin{align}
E[X_i] &= 1 - P(\text{both neighbors are black})\\
&=1-\frac{49*48}{100^2}=0.7648$.
\end{align} Thus, the desired quantity is equal to $38.24$.

Is this the correct approach? Could anyone point to the flaws?

**Correction:** the probability calculation is not right based on the comments. The correct one is
\begin{align}
1 - P(\text{both neighbors are black})&=\\
&=1- \frac{49*48}{99*98} \\
&=0.7575(75)
\end{align}
Hence, the correct answer is indeed $37.87$ or $1250/33$.

Comment: The idea is solid, but the calculation is a bit off.  The clockwise neighbor, say, is chosen from $99$ balls (as the one in question is already placed.  Given that the clockwise neighbor is in fact black, the counterclockwise neighbor is now chosen from $98$ balls.

Comment: @lulu is the answer $1250/33?$

Comment: @MatthewH. Yes, it is.